# how to toggle between a multiple English and Arabic in my website?

Tags: html, css

I'm a junior front-end developer based in Egypt, so most of what I work on will be in Arabic but I will also need to support English since it is the standard website language used.

I'm looking for a solution to help my clients toggle between multiple languages. Should I build an entire project twice or what is their a better solution to switch languages on a wbeite?

Please keep in mind that I'm still a junior developer with just 2 years of experience.

Comment: Please, first thing to do: read [ask], then you can create a question that fits StackOverflow patterns and then we can help. Right now, your question is off-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the language of websites in the `<html>` tag, e.g. `<html lang="en">`. Therefore, you should be able to save your original website/project in one language and then save another copy of your website/project with the other language you'd like to show.

[Read more about declaring languages in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)

If you want to do all of this on one page only, you can use JavaScript to change the page's language using an onclick function. [MDN has a good tutorial using onclick here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick). However, this is more complicated since you'll need to use a dictionary, such as [Google's Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate).

Comment: "You can use JavaScript to change the page's language using an onclick function" — How?

Comment: @Quentin Good catch. I was thinking of altering the `lang` attribute of elements, but you're not able to automatically translate using that. I believe you'd need a dictionary and translate using JavaScript, but simply changing the `lang` won't do anything.